# In Elixir, using a simple_one_for_one supervisor and start_child, how can I set the child's ID in the supervisor?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

Here is a simple test supervisor:

```
defmodule SupervisorTest.Worker.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def start_worker(args) do
    Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [args])
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      worker(SupervisorTest.Worker, [])
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
  end
end
```

And here is my even simpler worker:

```
defmodule SupervisorTest.Worker do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(args) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args)
  end

  def state(pid) do
    GenServer.call(pid, :state)
  end

  def stop(pid) do
    GenServer.stop(pid, :normal)
  end

  def handle_call(:state, _from, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end
end
```

I would ideally like to be able to call `Supervisor.which_children` with this supervisor and get back a list of children tuples, with the ID being a generated UUID.  It looks like I can't set it in the `init` `worker` statement.  And there is no `start_child/3` that takes options.  And I can't call `start_child/2` with the output of another `worker` statement...  So I see no method remaining to set the ID to something...  Any ideas?

This code written, when I call the `Supervisor.which_children`, the first element of each child tuple is `:undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [`Supervisor.which_children/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html#which_children/1) and [`superviser:which_children/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#which_children-1), this is not possible for `:simple_one_for_one` supervisors:

> `id` - as defined in the child specification or `:undefined` in the case of a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor

> `Id` - As defined in the child specification or `undefined` for a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor.

So, for `simple_one_for_one` supervisors, the first item of the returned tuples will always be `:undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

you can generate UUID in

```
def start_worker(args) do
  uuid = <generate UUID>,
  Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [args, uuid])
end
```

on the worker side:

```
def start_link(args, uuid) do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [args, uuid])
end

def init([args,uuid]) do
  {:ok, #State{ uuid: uuid }}
end
```

this way when you fetch which_children you can inquire about children's UUIDs via their pids.